# Typescript : Type 'Promise<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<void>'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following function :

```
let templateLoader = (onDidFinishLoad : Function, onDidFailLoad : Function) =>
    (url : string) : Promise<void> => 
        new Promise(    
            (resolve,reject) => {
                mainWindow.loadURL(url);
                mainWindow.webContents.once(
                    'did-finish-load',
                    () => { 
                        onDidFinishLoad(resolve);
                    }  
                );  
                mainWindow.webContents.once(
                    'did-fail-load', 
                    (event,errorCode,errorDescription) => {  
                        onDidFailLoad(reject,errorDescription); 
                    }  
                );   
            } 
        );
```

I've got the following compilation error:

> ERROR in [at-loader] ./app/loaders.ts:9:9
>       TS2322: Type 'Promise {}' is not assignable to type
>    Promise void.   Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'void'.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

it works by modifying `: Promise<void>` into `: Promise<any>`,

or to cast `new Promise` into `new Promise<void>`.

Comment: I get `Type declaration of 'any' loses type-safety. Consider replacing it with a more precise type.`

Comment: @jrwren if you know the precise type, you can replace both with `Promise<YourType>`.

Comment: @jrwren What if you are attempting to make it a reusuable component where it can have two types of Types being submit. i.e <DataOne> or <DataTwo>? Thanks in advance

Comment: @RogerPerez do `Promise<DataOne | DataTwo>`